# Achieve maximum sample rate for Keithley 2400 in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am trying to measure current vs time on a Keithley 2400 using LabVIEW. I've written the Keithley command in SCPI and currently measuring about 100 points per second, but I know that the Keithley has the scope to measure nearly 10 x of that.
Are there any obvious improvements that could be done to my code to improve the speed of data collection?

[image: a picture of my code]

Comment: did you try setting the sample rate?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use existing driver for LabVIEW - [instrument driver for Keithley 2400](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=1583).
2. I'm afraid that you do not parse data properly - usually, such devices return string with array of values, which you need to parse. Now, you just convert string to number - are you sure, that this is correct?
3. You need actually to get data from device, by TRACe:DATA? command. Check "C Data Flow" chapter of the [manual](http://research.physics.illinois.edu/bezryadin/labprotocol/Keithley2400Manual.pdf)

Overall, I beleive that if you will try official LabVIEW instrument driver for this device, you'll achieve proper acquisition implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Think about the architecture, Ideally you should have a ONLY Reading Loop, only reading from the hardware and enqueuing that data to another Consumer Loop. That means not disturbing the reading loop with any other conversion that can affect the time you are taking to acquire the data from the hardware.

So use one loop only for reading from the hardware and enqueue that data immediately. In another loop you can do all the conversions needed for that data and including the data in indicators, that is what is taking maybe more time.